# How to configure relationships between three tables?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I currently have the following three tables:

```
class Match(Base):
    
    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    tournament_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("myschema.tournament.id_"))


class Tournament(Base):

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)

    match = relationship("Match", backref="tournament")


class Weather(Base):

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    conditions = Column(String(50))
```

I'm looking to build a query that gets the weather conditions for every match in the `Match` table. Something like this:

```
qry = session.query(Match.id_, Weather.conditions)
qry = qry.select_from(Match)
qry = qry.join(Tournament, Weather)
qry = qry.all()
```

The unique key in `Weather` is the combination of `date_time`, `latitude` and `longitude` where:

- `date_time` needs to be joined to the equivalent in `Match` (many to many)
- `latitude` needs to be joined to the equivalent in `Tournament` (many to many)
- `longitude` needs to be joined to the equivalent in `Tournament` (many to many)

I'm ok with simple relationships on foreign keys, e.g. the one for `Match` and `Tournament`, but I get hopelessly lost trying to figure out anything more complex.

I'm hoping the above is self explanatory - if data is needed then please let me know and I'll add some.

I'm using SQLAlchemy v1.3.

---

**Update:**

I've been experimenting with trying to create the relationships from the guide [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths):

```
class Match(Base):

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    tournament_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("myschema.tournament.id_"))

    weather = relationship(
        "Weather", primaryjoin="Match.date_time == Weather.date_time"
    )

class Tournament(Base):

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)

    match = relationship("Match", backref="tournament")
    weather = relationship(
        "Weather",
        primaryjoin="and_(Tournament.latitude == Weather.latitude, " +
        "Tournament.longitude == Weather.longitude)"
    )


class Weather(Base):

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    conditions = Column(String(50))
```

However, when I run the query from above I get the error:

```
Don't know how to join to <class 'container.Weather'>. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option-1: plain query**

Actually, it is very similar to writing a plain SQL query:

```
qry = (
    session.query(Match.id_, Weather.conditions)
    .select_from(Match)
    .join(Tournament)
    .join(
        Weather,
        and_(
            Match.date_time == Weather.date_time,
            Tournament.latitude == Weather.latitude,
            Tournament.longitude == Weather.longitude,
        ),
    )
).all()
```

---

**Option-2: computed property**
After the clarification that you would like to have a "relationship", I actually think that instead of the `relationship` from Match to Weather it looks to be more efficient to use [`column_property`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) instead:

```
class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = "match"
    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    tournament_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tournament.id_"))

    # NOTE: Weather and Tournament should be defined earlier to use the expressions below. Otherwise, a stringified definition could be used instead
    weather_conditions = column_property(
        select([Weather.conditions.label("match_weather_conditions")])
        .where(tournament_id == Tournament.id_)
        .where(date_time == Weather.date_time)
        .where(Weather.latitude == Tournament.latitude)
        .where(Weather.longitude == Tournament.longitude)
        .as_scalar()
        .label("weather_conditions")
    )
```

This will query the `weather_conditions` whenever you query for `Match` as a property.

---

**FINALLY: Option-3: actual `relationship`**

Define the relationship as shown below (*without needing to change any other part of the model definitions*):

```
class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = "match"
    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    tournament_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tournament.id_"))

    weather = relationship(
        Weather,
        secondary=Tournament.__table__,
        primaryjoin=tournament_id == Tournament.id_,
        secondaryjoin=and_(
            Weather.latitude == Tournament.latitude,
            Weather.longitude == Tournament.longitude,
            date_time == Weather.date_time,
        ),
        viewonly=True,
        uselist=False,
    )
```

*The [Configuring how Relationship Joins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html) link you put in your question contains examples of similar solutions.*

Now, to perform the query you also need to specify the `join` condition to be able to use the query you want though:

```
q = session.query(Match.id_, Weather.conditions).join(Weather, Match.weather)
```

Comment: Thanks @van. I wanted to try and build a relationship within the tables rather than code the query. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: That was not quite clear from the question. Would you like a relationship from Match to Weather?

Comment: Hey @van - I think that's what I need. The key thing is just to be able to have the line `qry = qry.join(Weather)` and the joins themselves specified in the table structure rather than having to explicitly specify them in the query itself

Comment: Just seen the addition to your answer - presumably I no longer need the `qry = qry.join(Weather)` line now - I simply specify the `weather_conditions` field in the first line, i.e. `qry = session.query(Match.id_, Match.weather_conditions)`?

Comment: been thinking about this and I really need to go the relationship route. I've added some more detail to my question - hopefully this helps?

Comment: @Jossy, updated the answer adding also the `relationship` route option.

Comment: Thanks @van. Getting an error from this `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Join target <class 'container.Tournament'> does not correspond to the right side of join condition Match.weather`. Is there any way to add a join in just the form `qry = qry.join(Weather)`? I ask because the rest of my code builds multiple custom queries from hundreds of columns from dozens of tables. The way it is written currently is to add column names plus their associated table names as joins to the relevant query - I'll have to re-write things to accommodate named relationships or column properties!

Comment: If you are speaking of the query itself generating an issue, try `q = session.query(Match.id_, Weather.conditions).join(Weather, Match.weather)` (i corrected also the answer) as the previous might not have worked for previous versions of sqlalchemy (i am using 1.4+ now).

But if you indeed have many other joins in the query, one might need to do more work and be more explicit in relationships navigation. It is difficult to help without having more context though.

Answer (score 1):

Understandably, you want to utilize the relationship mapping of the ORM instead of writing explicit SQL (or mapped queries) outside of your class. To accomplish this, you need to be explicit about primary and secondary joins.

**Here's a solution using explicit primary and secondary joins:**

***Note:** The previous answer is both sufficient and correct, my solution is a different style of writing code, but the underlying behavior of the ORM will be nearly equal.*

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy


class Match(Base):

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    tournament_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("myschema.tournament.id_"))

    # Relationship for weather
    weather = relationship("Weather",
        secondary='Tournament',
        primaryjoin='Tournament.id == Match.tournament_id',
        secondaryjoin="""
            and_(
                Tournament.latitude == Weather.latitude,
                Tournament.longitude == Weather.longitude,
                Match.date_time == Weather.date_time
            )
        """,
        uselist=False,
        doc="""Join `Match` and `Weather` on `date_time` while using `Tournament`
        as an association table to match `[latitude, longitude]`.

        This will allow querying of the weather of a given match but will
        not allow updating of weather through a `Match` object.
        """
    )

    weather_conditions = association_proxy('conditions', 'weather',
        doc='Access the weather conditions without unpacking weather relationship')


class Tournament(Base):

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)

    match = relationship("Match", backref="tournament",
        doc='Join on `Tournament.id == Match.tournament_id`')

    weather = relationship("Weather",
        secondary='Match',
        primaryjoin='Tournament.id == Match.tournament_id',
        secondaryjoin="""
            and_(
                Tournament.latitude == Weather.latitude,
                Tournament.longitude == Weather.longitude,
                Match.date_time == Weather.date_time
            )
        """,
        uselist=False,
        doc="""Join `Tournament` and `Weather` on `[latitude, longitude]` while
        using `Match` as an association table to match `date_time`.

        This will allow querying of the weather of a given tournament but will
        not allow updating of weather through a `Tournament` object.
        """
    )

    weather_conditions = association_proxy('conditions', 'weather',
        doc='Access the weather conditions without unpacking weather relationship')
```

Comment: Thanks @Yaakov - this is definitely useful as it avoids the need to move the table classes around